# Ruby on rails associations parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to know, whatever the association is (simple belongs_to, polymorphic ...), when I make an association like :

```
class Toto < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :test_one
 belongs_to :test_two
end

class TestOne < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :totos
end

class TestTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :totos
end
```

and then

```
test_one = TestOne.create
test_two = TestTwo.create

test1 = test_one.totos.create
test2 = test_two.totos.create
```

I would like to know into a callback of Toto what object instantiate me. In this case, it's obviously `test_one` and then `test_two`. I know I could check ids for example but the problem is when i do :

```
test3 = test_one.totos.create(test_two: test_two)
```

I can't know if test3 was created through `test_one` or `test_two`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your example, I understand that you want to identify the type of object which is associated to your totos object (has_many :totos).

Since there are multiple different objects that might be associated to your totos object through the has_many and belongs_to associations, you might want to perform some kind of verification first to identify the type of the associated object.

### First Answer:

This will only work if you know beforehand all the object types that has_many :totos

```
if test3.respond_to?(:test_one)
  test = test3.test_one
elsif test3.respond_to?(:test_two)
  test = test3.test_two
end
```

### Second Answer:

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32471804/667127) on Stackoverflow, and it somehow answeres your question. So if I rephrase the answer to:

```
def get_belongs_to(object)
  associated = []
  object.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map do |reflection|
    associated << object.try(reflection.name)
  end
  associated.compact
end
```

This method will return an array of all objects associated to your totos object. This will also work when totos belongs to multiple objects say test_one and test_two at the same time. So the following:

```
associated_objects = get_belongs_to(test3)
```

and in your case `associated_objects[0]` will yield the object you desire.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did finally ... I hope a better solution is possible. Thank you ! :)

Comment: Thank you for the second answer. I already tried to use reflect_on_all_associations but I didn't keep it because it returns me an array of associations names (only belongs_to) but how can I be sure that the first one is the one used to create my children object ?

Comment: Thanks! This is what I thought would happen too. Thank you for letting me know. I will edit my answer and remove the wrong part.

Answer (score 0):

Rails does not persist the data you're looking for, so you'll have to store it yourself if you want it. This means you'll need a migration for the new field:

```
rails generate migration AddOriginalParentTypeToTotos original_parent_type:string
rake db:migrate
```

You can then override the assignment methods so that the first parent assigned will assign the `original_parent_type` attribute (and it will remain the same once assigned):

```
class Toto < ActiveRecord::Base
  def test_one=(val)
    self[:original_parent_type] ||= 'test_one'
    super
  end
  def test_one_id=(val)
    self[:original_parent_type] ||= 'test_one'
    super
  end
  def test_two=(val)
    self[:original_parent_type] ||= 'test_two'
    super
  end
  def test_two_id=(val)
    self[:original_parent_type] ||= 'test_two'
    super
  end
end
```

You can then use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send) to add an `original_parent` method:

```
class Toto < ActiveRecord::Base
  def original_parent
    send(original_parent_type) if original_parent_type
  end
end
```

Comment: This method is not really generic. If 'Toto' has 50 belongs_to relations, I won't create 100 instance methods which override default ones.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for what you wrote : A way to generalize this comportment. I haven't found yet excepting the solution I marked as the good one. If you have an idea about how to generalize the code you wrote here, I would like to see and understand it :). Thank you.